# Is it still possible for Labour to run the government?

Tags: election, united-kingdom, parliament

At the moment, the UK has a hung parliament from the recent election. The Conservatives and the DUP are now having a discussion to work with each other in order to run the government.

If the Conservatives and the DUP do not make a deal, is it still possible for Labour to win? If so, how would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, only if the Conservatives can't get a working majority and they can.

Basically, the party with the most seats usually gets the first opportunity to form a coalition or try to get a working majority. Only if that fails, then Labour will get a chance to form a government.

[This BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/election-2017-40209087) explains this quite clearly:

> **Who gets the first go at putting together a deal?**
>
> The Conservatives, as the government in power before the general election, get the first attempt at forming an administration.
>
> If it becomes clear that they cannot and Labour can, then Theresa May will be expected to resign. Mr Corbyn would then become the prime minister.
>
> But the Labour leader does not have to wait until Mrs May has exhausted all her options before he starts trying to put a deal of his own together.
> He can hold talks with potential partners at the same time as Mrs May. They may even be talking to the same people.

---

It's also worth mentioning that Labour [doesn't seem willing to form coalitions with other parties](http://www.newstatesman.com/politics/june2017/2017/06/john-mcdonnell-labour-will-form-minority-government) at the moment and rather govern as a minority government.

Labour's shadow chancellor John McDonnell [mentioned](http://www.newstatesman.com/politics/june2017/2017/06/john-mcdonnell-labour-will-form-minority-government) told the BBC:

> “Therefore, although [Labour] don’t have a majority, which I deeply regret, forming a minority government is the best opportunity of a government that will be stable in the interests of the country.”

---

However, Labour's quite short of a simple majority in the House of Commons and that will lead to trouble when passing legislative and [thus the government is unstable and unlikely to last long](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/0/hung-parliament1/). But it isn't unprecedented as former Labour Prime Minister Ramsay MacDonald took office in 1923 [even though Labour had lesser seats than the Conservatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1923).

> **Would that be sustainable?**
>
> Quite possibly not. Prime Minister Corbyn would be vulnerable to being brought down by a combination of Conservative and SNP votes. MacDonald’s government lasted only ten months before collapsing. Baldwin’s Conservatives won the October 1924 election handsomely.